# how to access a text file while debugging with eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, c, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am writing this code to access a file in eclipse CDT

```
ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;
string next;

inFile.open("input.txt");
if (inFile.fail())
{
    cout << "\nCould not open input.txt";
    exit(1);

}
```

the problem is when I try to debug my app or run my app from inside eclipse it cannot find the input.txt file. When I run my app from the console it works fine and opens the file. I need to debug the app but can't because for some reason the eclipse ide cannot find the file.

Where should I put the file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be an issue with relative paths.  Is `input.txt` in the root directory of your project?  Eclipse makes the top-level directory of the project the working directory.  If you replace `"input.txt"` in your code with the fully qualified file name, that should also work.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I was under the impression that it 'had' to be in the same directory as the executable if you refer to it with "filenameOnly.txt" But putting a copy of it into the project root sorted it out!

Comment: @georgelappies: Yeah I have no idea why Eclipse does it that way. You would definitely expect the working directory to be in the src or bin folder.

Comment: You can set this location using the "working directory" of the run/debug configuration. http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_run_dbg_arg.htm

Answer (score 4):

Other than moving your source input file, you may consider changing the working directory for launching the application.

By setting "Run Configurations" > [The RUN] > "Arguments" Tab > "Working directory" from "${workspace_loc:[Project Name]}" to something else like "${workspace_loc:[Project Name]}/Release", which is the usual binary target directory for Eclipse would do.

Answer (score 1):

Write a test program that creates file, such as "Here_I_Am.txt".

The directory where this is found will be the directory that the executable is using as the default directory.

Add paths to your filename as appropriate, relative to the "Here_I_Am.txt" file.  Or put your text file in the same directory as "Here_I_Am.txt"

Answer (score 1):

I found that with Eclipse, having the file in the root directory of the project should let it load. However, if you want to run it from the command line, the file needs to be in the same folder as the executable (something like Debug/ inside the project folder).

It should work to drag and drop the file into your Eclipse project. Just make sure that you select the option to Copy the file, rather than Link to it.

Answer (score 1):

After deselecting the use default button, select the folder containing your binary file. The binary file can be found under `Run configurations > Arguments > working directory`.