# ifstream objects from files in other directories in c++

Tags: c++, input, ifstream, subdirectory

I have saved all of the files that I intend to use as input streams in my application in a folder called "res". I am trying to use these files as input streams by building the string in the application and then opening them using something like this:

```
....
ifstream inputFile;
....
char fileName[30];
strcpy(fileName,"res/")
switch(num){
case 1:
    strcat(fileName,"file1");
case 2:
    strcat(fileName,"file2");
....
}

inputFile.open(fileName);
....
```

But the files are not opening and I don't know why; the `inputFile.is_open()` method is returning false. So I have 2 questions:

1. How do I refer to files in sub-directories and, for that matter, files in other folders in the parent directory?
2. Is there a better practice than the one I am using for doing what I'm trying to do above?? I am pretty sure there is!

I am using eclipse CDT on Ubuntu 12.04, and the g++-4.6 compiler, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Your cases fall through!

Comment: try using absolute paths, just for test. If everything is ok with absolute paths than you know that your relative paths are wrong (path must be relative to exe)

Comment: Thanks guys, using absolute paths worked. Also, I found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276164/how-to-access-a-text-file-while-debugging-with-eclipse-cdt which helped. Didn't know that the top level directory was the working directory in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

actually, right answer is given by david in comment.
you forgot breaks after cases and concatenate multiple names.
also with your mad skillz you better avoid strcat and other low-level functions and use std::string, or your next question will be about your program dumping core

Comment: thanks for the observation. I copied the code down in a hurry, the breaks was present in my program. I don't get the comment about dumping core though, is it because string objects are not restricted in length?

Comment: yes. you have to check lengths before calling strcat. but then you can just call memcpy. but why would you do this when you can just use std::string fn("dir/");fn += "file";

Comment: if you had breaks then program is correct, you probably ran it from wrong directory, but that would break even if you do not put files in subfolder. so for your first question - you correctly refer to subdirs, and for second - use absolute paths when you do not control cwd, do not use lowlevel functions for string concatenation, or even look at boost.filesystem

Comment: ah I see. Thanks a lot man, really appreciate it, as I'm still a beginner, and I need every piece of advice I can get.